# How can I install VLC on RHEL 6.3?

Tags: vlc-media-player, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm having a problem installing VLC on Red hat 6.3

When I try to use

```
yum install vlc
```

all goes well until it shows me this in the end:

> Error: Package: vlc-2.0.3-6.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
>              Requires: libminizip.so.1()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: liblrdf-0.5.0-2.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
>              Requires: ladspa
>
> Error: Package: libffado-2.1.0-0.8.20120325.svn2088.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
>              Requires: libconfig++.so.8()(64bit)

I'm running on a 32-bit processor and I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm running on 32bit processor and i don't know what's wrong

You are trying to install the 64-bit version of VLC based on the errors:

> Error: Package: vlc-2.0.3-6.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release) Requires:
>   libminizip.so.1()(64bit)

and

> Error: Package: libffado-2.1.0-0.8.20120325.svn2088.el6.x86_64
>   (linuxtech-release) Requires: libconfig++.so.8()(64bit)

You sure your processor is only a 32-bit that would mean its either fairly old ( i.e. over a decade ) or severaly limited and under powered.

Comment: it's Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.00GHz

Comment: >You are trying to install the 64-bit version of VLC based on the errors:

so what can I do to install the 32-bit version ?

Comment: @holddame - Use a 64-bit operating system considering the Pentium D is a 64-bit processor.